Does equivalence relation come from group acting on sublinear maps $f:\lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace \to \lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace$
I am considering maps $f:\lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace \to \lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace$ and denote the set of all these functions by $\mathcal{F}_n$ on which $S_n$ acts canonically like on $n$-vectors.
Now I am wondering about maps $f\in \mathcal{F}_n$ satisfying $f(s)\leq s$ for all $s\in\lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace$, which I call sublinear and denote the set of such $f$ by $\mathcal{F}_n^{(sl)}$. Sublinear maps exhibit a natural structure, which partitions them into equivalence classes given for $f,g\in $ by $f\sim g$ if and only if there are $\Phi :\lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace \to \lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace$ and $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $\Phi\circ \sigma\circ f=g$. Note that there are also $\Phi'$ and $\sigma'$ with $\sigma'\circ \Phi'\circ f=g$, so the roles of $\Phi$ and $\sigma$ "commute". Changing the values first and then adjusting the order or changing first the order and then adjusting the values accordingly is equivalent.
For example, writing for simplicity the maps in $\mathcal{F}_n^{(sl)}$ as vectors, for $n=4$ if $f=(1,1,1,2)$, then $g=(1,2,2,2)$ can be written as the composition of $\Phi\circ \sigma_{1,4}\circ f$ where $\Phi :\lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace \to \lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace$ with $\Phi(1)=2$ and $\Phi(2)=1$ and $\sigma_{1,4}$ swaps the first and fourth value. $f$ and $g$ are, hence, in this sense equivalent.
I am wondering whether this equivalence relation is induced by a group action of some group $\Gamma$. The inverse way, that any group action induces an equivalence relation, is well known, but how would one go about checking that an equivalence relation is induced by a group action?
Under such an action the equivalence classes would correspond to the orbits of $\Gamma$. I hope to count the number of equivalence classes by using orbit decomposition of $\mathcal{F}_n^{(sl)}$ under the action of $\Gamma$ (if such a $\Gamma$ exists).
The set $\mathcal{F}_n^{(sl)}$ cannot be fixed by any non-trivial subgroup of $S_n$ under the canonical action. This can be seen by choosing $f(s)=s$, such that for all $\sigma\in S_n\setminus\lbrace id\rbrace$ we have $\sigma(f)\not\in \mathcal{F}_n^{(sl)}$. This makes the map $\Phi$ introduced above necessary.
Alternatively, would there be an alternative way of counting the equivalence classes defined above?

What is the purpose of $\sigma$ in the equivalence relation? It seems to me that $\Phi\circ \sigma\in \mathcal{F}_n$, so we could have just picked $\Phi\circ \sigma$ in place of $\Phi$. It doesn't serve to restrict $\Phi$, either, since we can pick $\sigma$ to be the identity permutation.

I do not quite see how you would manage to find a $\Phi$ such that $\Phi\circ f=g$ in the example. After adjusting the values, you need to switch the order, to get $g$ also sub linear. The example motivates generally what I want to do.

Thanks, I just reread your description of S_n and realized my mistake.

For $X:={1,\dots, n}$, the standard notation for your $\mathcal F_n$ is $X^X$. Is $S_n$ the symmetric group of degree $n$? Can you explicitly define the action mentioned in the first paragraph?

OK, I will adjust the notation in the question. Yes, $S_n$ is the symmetric group of degree $n$ and the action on $X^X$ is given for $f\in X^X$ by identifying $f$ with the unique vector $(f_1,...,f_n)$ where $f_i=f(i)$, and then an element $\sigma\in S_n$ acting as $\sigma f=(f_{\sigma(1)},...,f_{\sigma(n)})$, I.e. as permutation of the vector.
